# Issue with Empty Results in ApexCodeCoverageAggregate after Validate with RunTest via ANT

Tags: soql, code-coverage, tooling-api, ant, sf-cli

I'm encountering an issue while trying to retrieve Apex class coverage after running a Validate with RunTest via ANT in Salesforce.

The problem arises because, for certain classes, the coverage report generated by ANT doesn't show 0%, however, when using the above query, the results consistently show 0% coverage.

This is the ANT parameter for the validate:

```
<sf:deploy username="${sf.username}"
           password="${sf.password}"
           serverurl="${sf.serverurl}"
           deployRoot="${artifactPath}/deployDelete_pack"
           ignoreWarnings="true"
           pollWaitMillis="600000"
           maxPoll="900"
           checkOnly="true"
           testLevel="RunSpecifiedTests">
    &tests;
</sf:deploy>
```

Inside the `&test` there are test classes found inside the package.

To retrive coverage after ANT execution I've followed the following steps:

1. Extracted the APEX classes from the package using a bash script that excludes test classes (without @isTest or testMethod).
2. Subsequently, I created a SOQL query to obtain the desired results:

```bash
class_list=$(awk -F/ '{gsub(".cls", "", $NF); print "\x27"$NF"\x27"}' "$APEX_FILE_RUN" | paste -sd "," -)
SOQL_RUN="SELECT Id, ApexClassOrTrigger.Name, NumLinesCovered, NumLinesUncovered, Coverage FROM ApexCodeCoverageAggregate WHERE ApexClassOrTrigger.Name IN ($class_list)"
```

3. Executed the query using an authFile to connect the pipeline terminal to the target org.

```bash
sf org login sfdx-url -s --sfdx-url-file authFile.json
sf data query --query "$SOQL_RUN" --use-tooling-api --json > "$APEX_COVERAGE_QUERY_RESULT"
```

The problem is that the query results often return empty, as shown below:

```json
"attributes": {
    "type": "ApexCodeCoverageAggregate",
    "url": "/services/data/v59.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexCodeCoverageAggregate/xxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "Id": "7151l000000bDkgAAE",
  "ApexClassOrTrigger": {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "Name",
      "url": "/services/data/v59.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexClass/xxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "Name": "yyyyyyyyyyyyy"
  },
  "NumLinesCovered": 0,
  "NumLinesUncovered": 15,
  "Coverage": {
    "coveredLines": [],
    "uncoveredLines": []
  }
}
```

I can't figure out why the results are empty despite the test execution. Can anyone help me understand what might be the issue or suggest alternative approaches to retrieve Apex class coverage after running Validate with RunTest?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does the package you are deploying include Apex Classes for which you are trying to get coverage?
If not then you may be experiencing the issue described here: 
 https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/84797/metadata-deploy-test-code-coverage-report-is-broken-in-metadata-api-v34-0-sum ?

Comment: Yes, i check agane just now:

`<types> <members>xxxxxxxx</members> <name>ApexClass</name> </types>`

More over, with the same `package.xml`, ant run the tests and create his report

Comment: Note that [Ant has been retired](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_deployment_ant_migration_tool_eol.htm&release=248&type=5).  You should start transitioning your work to [SF CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/salesforcecli).

Comment: Oh... I don't see this change. Sad story...
Anyway, you think the problem is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @David Cheng
we discovered that ANT is no longer supported.
In its place the command:

```
sf project deploy validate
```

with the appropriate options it allows you to perform the same functionality, and indeed, it is possible to receive detailed and generic coverage information directly from here.

Here is a specific example for my case:

```
sf project deploy validate --verbose --coverage-formatters json-summary --coverage-formatters json --test-level RunSpecifiedTests --tests test1 test2 --manifest testManifest/package.xml
```